# Using gluPerspective()

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, sdl

I'm learning OpenGL; I managed to make my first 2D program but I am stuck on using gluPerspective.

I'm trying a little test to try to grasp how I can go about making a 3D project but I can't seem to figure out what I am missing and what is needed to make this small test work:

```
void init_perspective()

{

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING); 
SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_OPENGL); 
SDL_WM_SetCaption( "OpenGL Test", NULL ); 

glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 ); 
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45, 1.333, 0, 100); 
glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

}

int main( int argc, char **argv)

{

init_perspective();

glTranslatef( 200, 200, 50 );
glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex3f(0, 0 ,0);
    glVertex3f(50,0 ,10);
    glVertex3f(50,50,30);
    glVertex3f(0, 50,0);

glEnd();

glLoadIdentity();

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

SDL_Delay(1000);

SDL_Quit();

return 0;

}
```

If anybody could tell me what function calls I could use and are missing in this test code so I could have a play around and learn how 3D OpenGL works I would be grateful.

Comment: What's SDL? I've been working for awhile with OpenGL and haven't seen SDL.

Comment: Never heard of it, I always used OpenGL for that. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> gluPerspective(45, 1.333, **0**, 100);

Never set zNear to zero.  It messes up [the math](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml):

> Because `r = zFar / zNear` approaches infinity as `zNear` approaches 0, `zNear` must never be set to 0.

Choose some small positive number like `0.01` or `12`.

EDIT: Also, put your camera somewhere such that it can see your geometry:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
init_perspective();

glTranslatef(0,0,-5);
glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-1,-1);
    glVertex2f( 1,-1);
    glVertex2f( 1, 1);
    glVertex2f(-1, 1);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

SDL_Delay(1000);

SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

By default it's looking down the -Z axis from position (0,0,0).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wondered why some code examples I have seen always have zNear set to 0.1f or similar. I changed the value to 1 in my code but I don't think that is the major problem

Comment: The issue with setting it to 1 is that if your camera is less than 1 unit away from an object, then the object will not be rendered. On the other hand, setting zNear to a too small value can lead to rendering artefacts, since you have a finite precision zBuffer.

Comment: I was wondering if I need to use ViewPorts when using gluPerspective(). When I used glOrtho I never had to use ViewPorts because it will generally project the entire orthogonal view set up in glOrtho

Comment: @Michael: The viewport defines the portion of the window you want to render in. You can use this to render multiple views in a single window, or for pixel coordinate based rendering in the corners, edges.

Comment: How do I get the "camera" to look down the positive Z axis or do people tend to work down the -Z axis?

Comment: I always use `1.0` as my zNear. I find it to be good practice because it better models the eyeball. You have the point of convergence, and then you have a frustum out a bit, which represents your eyeball. Sure, you cannot render things closer than 1 unit away, but the positioning looks unrealistic at that point anyway. It's like the object is stabbing your eye.

Comment: As for looking down the positive Z axis, you need to alter row 4 column 3 of the perspective matrix to be +1 instead of -1. I don't know if gluPerspective can do this. I just know that that is where it happens mathematically.

Comment: Or you can rotate around the X axis by 180 degrees :)